# How can I safely overload custom deleter of std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am trying to reduce code duplication while using `std::unique_ptr` and it's custom deleter.

I have the some containers `Foo`, `Bar` which are allocated using *one* custom allocator, so cannot be freed with `delete`.

So the current code is:

```
struct UniqueFooDeleter
{
   void operator()(Foo* foo) 
   {
      internal_free(foo);
   }
};
using unique_foo_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Foo, UniqueFooDeleter>;

struct UniqueBarDeleter 
{
   void operator()(Bar* bar) 
   {
      internal_free(bar);
   }
};
using unique_bar_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Bar, UniqueBarDeleter>;
```

I changed it to:

```
struct UniqueInternalDeleter
{
   void operator()(Bar* bar)
   {
      internal_free(bar);
   }

   void operator()(Foo* foo)
   {
      internal_free(foo);
   }
};
using unique_bar_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Bar, UniqueInternalDeleter>;
using unique_foo_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Foo, UniqueInternalDeleter>;
```

How can I do better such that any number of containers that are allocated via `internal_free` can be used as `std::unique_ptr`s ?

Comment: Why do you worry about `std::unique_ptr<Tri, UniqueInternalDeleter>`? You'll get a compile-time error once you try to **use** a variable of this type.

Comment: @Evg sadly I rushed over this.. IDE didn't complain, so I didn't compile it. Let me change the post.

Comment: To simplify `UniqueInternalDeleter` make `operator()` a template that accepts any `T` and either make it the responsibility of a user to provide correct deleter or use `static_assert` similar to JeJo's answer.

Comment: For your thirst edit/ question update, simplest what I can think, you can provide a variable template which chek the types which are allowed and use `static_assert` in the answer provided: `template<typename Container>
inline constexpr bool hasInternalFreeAllocator
= std::is_same_v<T, Foo> || std::is_same_v<T, Bar> || other container....;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `UniqueInternalDeleter` as templated functor and [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert), if the `T` is not `Foo` or `bar`.

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same_v

template<typename T>
struct UniqueInternalDeleter /* final */
{
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, Foo> || std::is_same_v<T, Bar>,
      " T must be either Foo or Bar");

   void operator()(T* barOrfoo)
   {
      internal_free(barOrfoo);
   }

private:
   void internal_free(T* barOrfoo)
   {
      if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, Foo>)
         // code for `Foo*`
      else
         // code for `Bar*`

   }
};
```

This makes the your alias to be more specific for `Bar` and `Foo`:

```
using unique_bar_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Bar, UniqueInternalDeleter<Bar>>;
using unique_foo_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Foo, UniqueInternalDeleter<Foo>>;
```

Comment: I suggest you move `template` inside deleter and make `operator()` a template.

Comment: Jejo: I made the question a bit more specific: The problem as of now is that I'd be having a chain of `||` in the  assert in the deleter when there are several containers.   CC @Evg

Comment: @JeJo, I guess, no. But not mentioning the type looks like a big advantage.

Comment: JeJo, `internal_free` accepts `void*`, so the code in `private` is not required for my use case. You may keep it for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
template<class> struct needs_internal_free : std::false_type { };

struct unique_internal_deleter {
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T* ptr) const {
        static_assert(needs_internal_free<T>::value);
        internal_free(ptr);
    }
};

template<class T>
using unique_internal_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, unique_internal_deleter>;
```

Now we can declare specific types:

```
template<> struct needs_internal_free<Foo> : std::true_type { };
using unique_foo_ptr = unique_internal_ptr<Foo>;

template<> struct needs_internal_free<Bar> : std::true_type { };
using unique_bar_ptr = unique_internal_ptr<Bar>;
```

Comment: @JeJo, sure. I just wanted to decouple `needs_internal_free` (or `use_...`, not sure if the new name is good) from `Foo`, `Bar`, etc., so that new types could be added by adding independent specializations. Otherwise, `needs_internal_free` looks redundant.